# Problem with bcp

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to load my table with some data using bcp. Below is the bcp command that I am using

```
bcp Job.DBO.FileWatch in ABC.txt -C -t\t -S server\rept -T -f bcp1.fmt
```

The schema of the FileWatch table is like this. It is just a dummy table

[image]

And the ABC.txt file from where I am reading the data is like this

[image]

And the format file looks like this.

[image]

But when I run my bcp command, it is not throwing any error and at the same time no rows are copied. I read every link on Google's first and second page and tried every switch they mentioned but still it was not working. Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

What is `-C` (*upper case*)? That's for the code page.

You should have `-C { ACP | OEM | RAW | *code_page* }` according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

I think you mean `-c` (*lower case*), which is for the character data type.